# ATL::CWindowImpl<main_window>::Create access violation

Tags: dll, project, atl

I create an simple DLL project using the ATL, code is like:

```
class main_window : 
    public wtlext::LayeredWindow<ATL::CWindowImpl<main_window>, bool>,
    public CVWModule,
    public IPropertyObserver
{
// Construction
public:
    main_window();
    ~main_window();

    HWND Create(HWND hWndParent)
    {
        ATL::CWindowImpl<main_window>::Create(hWndParent, rcDefault, NULL,
            WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,
            WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED);

        return m_hWnd;
    };
}
```

character is unicode  and runtimelibrary is MDd

Exeptional cauht:
code 0xC0000005
Type:Access Violation
Description: the thread attempted to read from or write to a virtual address for whick it does not have the appropriate access .
exe 中的 0x76fe8dc9 处最可能的异常: 0xC0000005: 写入位置 0x00000014 时发生访问冲突

Sorry for inconvenience, first time to post here .
I found the exe used CAPPMODULE ,besides I found the project used WTL.
below the DLL main CPP.
`
    //#include "stdafx.h"
    //#include "iconized.h"
    //#include "iconizedDlg.h"

```
// #define UNICODE
// #define _UNICODE 

CAppModule _Module;



HINSTANCE hDll_Instance;
HWND hWnd;


extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{



    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {

            hDll_Instance = (HINSTANCE)hModule;



            //ShowWindow();
        }
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        {

        }

        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:

        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:{

        ;
                            }
                            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

 int WINAPI Iconized_tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/, LPTSTR lpstrCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 {
    //AtlAxWinInit();
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput; 
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken; 
    int nRet = -1;


    // this resolves ATL window thunking problem when Microsoft Layer for Unicode (MSLU) is used
    ::DefWindowProc(NULL, 0, 0, 0L);

    // create VW module window as soon as we can
    iconized::main_window *pMainWnd = new iconized::main_window;
    assert(pMainWnd != 0);

    // Init module (ATL magic starts here)
    HRESULT  hRes = _Module.Init(NULL, hInstance);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hRes));

    AtlInitCommonControls(ICC_COOL_CLASSES | ICC_BAR_CLASSES);  // add flags to support other controls

    // Init GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    // create main window
    if(pMainWnd->Create(0) == NULL)
    {
    ATLTRACE(_T("Main window creation failed!\n"));
    return 0;
    }

    pMainWnd->ShowWindow(nCmdShow);

    // Run main message loop
    CMessageLoop theLoop;
    _Module.AddMessageLoop(&theLoop);

    nRet = theLoop.Run();

    _Module.RemoveMessageLoop();

    // main window must be destroued before GDI+ is shutdown 
    // in order to release its resources properly
    pMainWnd->Destroy();

    // Finalize GDI+
    Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    _Module.Term();

    delete pMainWnd;

//#ifdef USE_MEMTRACK
//    std::stringstream s;
//    MemTrack::TrackDumpBlocks(s);
//    ::MessageBox(0, s.str().c_str(), "Memblocks", MB_OK);
//#endif

     return 0;
 }
```

`

Comment: More info needed, you are doing something wrong but it's not clear what exactly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
The start reason is that I want to change a exe project to  dll project so that I could use it as plugin in another project.   
Those code worked well in the exe, but got exception in the DLL, and I tracked; 
when it goes to the 
CWindowImpl::create->  T::GetWndClassInfo().Register(&m_pfnSuperWindowProc)-> ... if (FAILED(lock.Lock())) 
then 
`code`inline HRESULT CComCritSecLock< TLock >::Lock() throw()
{
 HRESULT hr;

 ATLASSERT( !m_bLocked );
 hr = m_cs.Lock();//exception caught 
 if( FAILED( hr ) )
 {
  return( hr );
 }
 m_bLocked = true;

 return( S_OK );
}
`code`

Comment: You can edit your question and this way the code would be well formatted. Otherwise it's hard to read it. Exception in `lock`? You might have not defined `CAtlDllModule` descendent well. Anyway it's worth looking at call stack at the time of exception.

Comment: the code and further detail is put as the 1st answer.

Comment: I could not post the code and further detail is put as the answer for I am new here . Sorry for inconvenience, first time to post here .  
I found the exe used CAPPMODULE ,what should I do in order to change it into dll, besides I found the project used WTL.
below the DLL main CPP.

Comment: post the code in the theme through editing. Is the CAtlDllModule you mentioned corresponding to the CAPPModule for EXE.

Comment: I think you are still not doing it right with modules. You could perhaps create an empty ATL DLL project and see how to do it right.

Comment: thanks.I would have a try. Later I found it was a WTL project,then I am looking into how to create a right WTL DLL, info would be updated.

Comment: Now I found I use C to call my C++dll, there is error, but if I use a new C++ test app to call it, the error does not come out. use ms verifier to check, the error is like:'

===========================================================
VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000013: pid 0x1864: first chance access violation for current stack trace 

 0000000000000010 : Invalid address being accessed
 000000005731B5D6 : Code performing invalid access
 000000000898EAF0 : Exception record. Use .exr to display it.
 000000000898E600 : Context record. Use .cxr to display it.`

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, the reason is No call to InitializeCriticalSection(...);for I used the loadlibrary(*.dll),which leave the global variables(_AtlWinModule，_AtlBaseModule,_AtlComModule which is used by ATL components later) uninitialized.
So in this situation,  Adding _CRT_INIT to the DLLMain  could overcome the access vialation, the crt_INIT function could help initialize the related global varible.
like :

```
DLLMain增加_CRT_INIT (ul_reason_for_call)
 {
 case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  {
   //_CRT_INIT(hModule,ul_reason_for_call,lpReserved);}
```